# What camera settings may affect a RAW photo?

Tags: raw, camera-settings

I know this is too general question, but I'll give it a try..

---

About an hour research in photo.SE, I found some question, that are related to this one:

- [Does the camera white balance setting affect the raw image at all?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/does-the-camera-white-balance-setting-affect-the-raw-image-at-all) - short answer - **NO**
- [Why is Aperture changing the color of my RAW photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/why-is-aperture-changing-the-color-of-my-raw-photos) - no short answer :D
- [Does "long exposure noise reduction" option make any difference when shooting RAW?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/does-long-exposure-noise-reduction-option-make-any-difference-when-shooting-raw) - short answer - **YES**
- [Is in-camera high-ISO noise reduction worthwhile?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/is-in-camera-high-iso-noise-reduction-worthwhile) - one more about noise reduction
- [Do different "Picture styles" affect RAW output?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13271/do-different-picture-styles-affect-raw-output) - short answer - **NO**

Shutter speed and aperture are obvious, of course.

---

What other settings may affect a RAW photo?

Comment: see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6628/whats-real-and-whats-virtual-on-a-digital-camera/6630#6630

Comment: One comment. Aperture you realate to here with link is software no Aperture in camera.

Comment: OMG, downvote again?! Why? Because of the similar question? How I'm supposed to find it, as the titles are completely different. I can't read all questions, one by one, to catch if something (comment, or answer, or whatever) will answer my question.. Also - downvote for duplicate? Oh, come on.. Or it's something else? I got downvote for almost all of my questions and I still don't know why. The criteria here for up/down votes seems to be really different from the criteria in stackoverflow O.o

Comment: Picture styles etc. do affect raw output in the sense that metadata is attached which is interpreted by some raw conversion tools. The question ought to state what setting affect the raw sensor data.

Comment: @Kiril downvote was probably due to the question being very open ended, there are hundreds of camera settings across many models which will indirectly affect your raw capture. I've tried to list the more common ones.

Comment: Power on/off setting has severely affected some of my photos (sorry, no examples to show).

Comment: @Kiril Kirov - They fairly recently made question downvotes free of rep penalties, so we're seeing more question downvotes in general.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

settings which influence actual exposure:

- shooting mode TV,AV,M etc.
- shutter speed
- aperture
- ISO
- exposure compensation
- safety shift (Canon)
- flash (on/off)
- flash exposure compensation
- active D lighting (Nikon) - affects raw capture by underexposing for highlights
- exposure bracketing
- exposure lock
- metering mode
- focus screen setting (telling the camera which screen you're using affects metering reading)

others

- mirror lock-up
- image stabilisation
- long exposure noise reduction
- any setting which relates to the AF system
- raw image size e.g. medium raw, small raw
- crop mode (Nikon)
- sensor cleaning
- focus microadjust

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive list (you really went through the whole menu system, didn't you? :-), but how does Exposure Bracketing affect the RAW? Also I think you should remove the parentheses part in IS.

Comment: @ysap slightly tenuous, but if you change the bracketing setting from -+1 stop to -+2 stops you'll get different raw images...

Comment: @ysap if image stabilisation cannot be deactivated from camera body, it still *does* affect RAW, but it's not a *camera* setting. Similarly, aperture might not be a *camera* setting with some lenses, and flash settings are camera settings mostly for popup flash only.

Comment: Even if you're using an old manual lens with no aperture linkage, the aperture setting on the camera will influence other settings in certain modes, e.g. Av, as the camera assumes you're moving the aperture ring when you shift aperture, which may not be the case. Just about any setting can alter your exposure in some circumstance or other, making it pretty difficult to enumerate all of them!

Comment: @Imre - this is really - **really** - an argument on semantics. "Camera" may be regarded as the whole system, including any accessory connected and activated by the shutter button. If you want to make sure the interpretation is what you and Matt say, then name it "Camera Body settings". What's more, the OP did not restrict the discussion to SLR's (or interchangeable lens systems in general), so how will you make the distinction between lens/camera for other camera systems?

Comment: @Matt - but there *are* settings that *do not* alter your (RAW) exposure, e.g. White Balance.

Comment: You may add Live-View to the list. Most DSLRs cameras meter different in live-view than when using the OVF. Also Dynamic-Range (Fuji), DRO (Sony), Highlight Correction (Pentax) Composition Adjustment (Pentax) and RAW File-Format (Pentax).

Comment: I really meant "the whole camera system". Thanks, great answer! So, could you list some (basic, as there are too many of them) options, that will not affect the RAW? It's not directly asked in the question, but I'm curious. And if I ask it in another question, I bet I'll get tons of down-votes, unfortunately. I mean - contrast, brightness control, while balance, .. Actually, I can't think of others. Or such question actually can't be answered and anything, of of this list, will not affect RAW? Sorry for the dummy questions..

Comment: @ysap - you're dead right, it would have been quicker to list the setting that don't affect the raw!!