# How to get 'plastic' skin tones in a picture?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, effect, retouching

I know [this is a very complex photo](http://500px.com/photo/7509560), but I'm interested in knowing how the skin tones were achieved which I believe is an almost but not quite, a plastic look. Are there tutorials out there on this? I can't seem to find the right search terms for such an effect.

Comment: often this is called the "Dave Hill" look after commercial photographer Dave Hill. Have a look at this question/answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/how-does-one-create-the-dave-hill-effect-for-portraits-action-shots