# Lightroom - Vivid faces effect

Tags: lightroom

I'm trying to figure out the name of this effect and how to achieve it in Lightroom or Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: It's [colloquially] called the "Dave Hill Effect", or at least it used to be, and you achieve it in the studio, not in Lightroom. See this question for more info: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/how-does-one-create-the-dave-hill-effect-for-portraits-action-shots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light is very specific on those photos, like the one Matt is pointing, you can try a combination of a rim light + butterfly light.

But they also have some manipulation on post.

**Some styles you can explore**

The two styles you can explore that comes to my mind are:

- **Dragan style**
- **Tone Mapping (hdri)**

Both are based on adjusting contrast, but the Tone mapping is a special manipulation of the contrast called micro contrast. This is not only a contrast on the overall image, but in adjacent zones. You can try some dodge and burn.

**Some specific manipulations you can try**

- Contrast.
- Saturation, lower it or perhaps play with a Gradient Map https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=photoshop+gradient+map.

Of course the styles can be very exaggerated or very subtle.

Comment: Or simply using [a high-pass filter](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2010/02/after-light-high-pass-post-production.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily recreate this effect using Topaz Clarity. Check out the bearded guy on [this link](http://www.topazlabs.com/clarity).

In general, you do local and microcontrast enhancement.

Comment: This tool is very cool, however I'm accepting Rafael's answer because he provided some question-related techniques. Also, Matt Grum didn't move the comment to an answer, which would be accepted since he was first and correct.